# My birthday is coming/coming up

Tags: word-usage

If I am telling someone who doesn't know when's my birthday,  while not being precise,  will it be natural to use 'coming'?  I guess it doesn't sound idiomatic though it's grammatical.  Will it be better to use "coming up"?

> My birthday is coming.
>
> My birthday is coming up.

I guess the second sentence natural whereas the first one does not.....

Comment: Had *The Game of Thrones* used "winter is coming up" it just wouldn't have had the same ring to it as "winter is coming." But which form to use is a matter of personal opinion and context. Neither is necessarily *better*. (*Is coming up* has a jaunty sound to it, whereas just *is coming* seems more portentous.)

Comment: I think that in the context of talking about your birthday, "coming" would sound pompous.  I like the more informal "coming up" better for birthdays.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the comments.

> "Is coming up" has a jaunty sound to it, whereas just "is coming" seems
>   more portentous." – Jason Bassford

and which is more appropriate for a *birthday*, jaunty or portentous? usually the first choice.

> I think that in the context of talking about your birthday, "coming"
>   would sound pompous. I like the more informal "coming up" better for
>   birthdays. – aparente001

the more informal "coming up" sounds less pompous, and usually would fit better for birthdays.

Comment: Thank you. How about "My birthday is coming soon"?

Comment: @WXJ96163 you could say that.